# Why divergent integals regularization cannot be used to solve Seeliger paradox?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, renormalization, regularization

In Russian Wikipedia [it is claimed](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81) that Seeliger paradox was the main problem of Newtonian theory of gravitation.

The article suggests several proposed solutions to the paradox, but neither of them uses the regularization of divergent integrals.

So, my question is, why we cannot regularize the divergences, say, with Cauchy main values so go get rid of the infinite potentials?

Yes, the result would depend on the filtering of summation and the starting point, but a natural answer here would be that we should start at the test point itself and sum over symmetric shells around it.

As a result, a test point in a spherical vacuum bubble in infinite, uniformly dense universe should be attracted to the closest wall of the bubble.

Author who suggests the same (1989): http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1989Ap%26SS.159..169H but arguing from symmetry.

Comment: Please explain what the Seeliger paradox is, for those of us who can’t read Russian. I have never heard of it.

Comment: @G.Smith https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/2580_Cosmology/problems.html

Comment: @Anixx You need to briefly state the paradox (not just link to it) by editing some text into the question (not just adding a comment).  On Physics SE questions have to be able to stand alone, even if links go dead (and links do often go dead).